# Export Gridview to Excel / additional Content

Tags: excel, gridview, export

I have a grdiview and a button on my page that export the content to an Excel file,What I would like to add is to have companies logo,Title,Today's Date and Time as well.

Any Idea? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

[SpreadsheetGear for .NET](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/) can do it.

You can probably find a sample which comes close to what you want to do in our ASP.NET Samples for C# & VB - perhaps one of the "Excel Reporting" samples or one of the "Excel to Datagrid and Back" samples. Our ASP.NET samples are [here](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/support/samples/).

You can try it for yourself with the free trial which is [here](https://www.spreadsheetgear.com/downloads/register.aspx).

Disclaimer: I own SpreadsheetGear LLC

Answer (score 0):

[Matt Berseth](http://mattberseth.com/blog/2007/04/export_gridview_to_excel_1.html) has a way to do this, however it does not export native Excel files.

It's free, though.